# Reporting tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our organization has a reporting application, that queries a real time transaction table to pull data for reports. As the query is against transaction table that is continuously updated the report performance is dismal. We are trying to come up with a new DB design to improve the performance.

My idea is to have three different tables for each year (eg; reports_2014,reports_2015,reports_2016) ( as we need to report only last three years of data) which will be created at the end of the year from the real time DB. The current year table (reports_2016) on the reporting DB will be updated with new records for the previous day at midnight. My reporting query will use a view that will be a union all of these three tables + the data from real time table for records from midnight to till this point in time.

Initially, I felt this to be a good design, provided I am going to have good indexes on these history tables.

However, I have a catch here arising from the inherent application design that updates these real time tables.
The status column of a transaction record can change to cancelled if I am cancelling a transaction , along with a new transaction cancellation record.
I could capture this by having a AFTER insert trigger and capturing the updates made correctly.

Now the issue is when there is a cancel record that is posted during the time my ETL to copy last days data to history table runs, I miss the update.

How do I capture this? Is there a way to delay the trigger untill my ETL is complete? Or is there a better approach to this problem?

My apologies if this is not the right place to post this question.

Thanks,
Roopesh

Comment: In the **first** instance you might find that adding a whole load of RAM to your server will solve your performance issues. Which is way simpler than building a data warehouse. But anyway I don't quite understand your 'cancel' issue. There are many ways to replicate data. The next level of complexity is that you take say a week of data and delete and reload it. Another way is to use a 'date last updated' field to work out what to load. Another way is to write all changes to a logging table and go through that logging table and load only changes logged in there each time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Nick.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Nick. The API does not update the last update column if it is updating a history record. So as you mentioned we should capture the updates in a log table and push it to the reporting table regularly. The issue is that it is a real time reporting system now. If we implement a log capture, it cant be real time but a near real time. And yeah, RAM addition is an option we are looking at. I was thinking of something that we can do from the software/DB/Query side to make it better.

Comment: I just read below that you are actually reporting of a database mirror - is that correct? This has just added to my confusion. Anyway with regards to RAM it is often far cheaper and convenient to just throw RAM at the problem, cost wise and maintenance wise. Database optimisation is the 'proper' way to fix this but it requires a longer term level of maintenance.

Comment: Yes Nick, It is a mirrored DB which is instantly mirrored from production transaction DB. I also learned today that the reporting application should only display last three years of data. As per my understanding and reading I have now options from software side of the problem. One- To have the table portioned , Second- Cash the reports (we have 17 RDL files. There are many variants of them. But they all use the same base query) every day around midnight and use that cashed data in reports... I am not sure if it would results in missing current data..I am still looking for the best option ..

Comment: You need to work out 'acceptable latency' latency = how out of date the data is. If say one hour is acceptable then yes by all means cache the data and load it into a reporting table every hour. But if they then require it every 5 minutes that will not work. Business is short sighted and often they ask for short term things (only three years) thinking it will be easy but then when they change that it requires a system rearchitecture which should've been considered in the first place. If latency of say one hour is acceptable another great solution is a SSAS cube

Comment: Oh and keep in mind that adding RAM is just another way of caching except that you don't have to go and build summary tables and jobs to populate them etc. and your cache is automatically up to date

Answer (score 3):

Multiple parallel tables with the same structure is almost never a good idea for a database design.  Databases offer two important methods for handling performance:

- Indexes
- Partitioning

as well as other methods, such as rewriting queries, spatial indexes, full text indexes, and so on.

In your case, instead of multiple tables, consider table partitions.

As for your process, you should be using the creation/modification date of records.  I would envision a job running early in the morning, say at 1:00 a.m., and this job would gather the previous day's records.  Any changes after midnight simply do not apply.  They will be included the following day.

If the reporting needs to be real-time as well, then you should consider building the reporting into the application itself.  Some methods are:

- Following the same approach as above, but doing the reporting runs more frequently (say once per hour rather once per each day).
- Modifying the existing triggers to handle updates to reporting tables as well as the base tables.
- Wrapping all DML transactions in stored procedures that handle both the transactional tables and the reporting tables.
- Re-architecting the system to use queues with multiple readers to handle the disparate processing needs.

Comment: As more more I think about it the solution seems to be partitioning the transaction table. Now what I am not sure about is, is it feasible to implement partitioning on the subscriber if the publisher is not partitioned.

Comment: I suggest you make a backup of the system, apply partitioning and test. It may not actually make much difference.

Comment: Nick, I am trying it now. Will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Gordon for your inputs. At this point ours is a real time reporting system. The database is a mirrored instance of production transactional database. Whenever a new transaction is entered to production database the same record flows to reporting database, which has the exactly similar schema, instantly. We do have indexes on columns those are queried frequently, however as there are many inserts in every hour the index performance is degraded quite fast. We rebuild them once in two weeks and it takes around 8 hours. That is where I thought having indexes on this huge transaction table with many inserts every hour may not be a good idea.. Please correct me if I am wrong...

I am actually reading through partitioning to see if it is a viable option for me. I had a discussion on the same with our DBA and I got following comment from him *'The reporting database is a mirrored instance of real time production database. You have to implement partitioning on the production transactional database. If you are using partitioning on a mirrored instance that would not work as your actual source DB is not partitioned'* I am not sure how far this is true. Do you know if there is such a dependency between partitioning and mirroring??

Comment: I think that database mirroring requires exactly the same underlying schema.  There may be other replication options that have a bit more flexibility.